# SSMS: Pipe Delimited output

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to output the results from a query to a pipe delimited file.

I followed these instructions:

> Tools--> Options --> Query Results --> Sql Server --> Results to Text.
>   Change output format from Tab Delimited to Custom Delimited.
>   Put a Pipe in the Custom Delimiter Box.
>   Go back to your query select Query --> Results to File. Execute file, Give it a Disk path and a name.

but when I converted the .rpt file to .txt [...also in instructions ...], I don't see any pipes.

1. *Should* I be ***seeing*** pipes between the field values?
2. If so, is there something missing or incorrect in the instructions?

Answer (score 13):

You need to open a new query window. Settings changes do not apply for existing query windows.